# SSMS Setting for query result time limit

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I had someone prank me by changing the query execution time limit to 15 seconds.  I have changed it more times than I can count. I have used the reset to default button and I have manually typed in the change. I have changed the limit to a really large number of seconds etc.

Sometimes the hard limit of 15 seconds will go away, but it ALWAYS comes back and this particular time I
cannot seem to make it change.

Does anyone have any idea what I can do to try and make this issue go away once and for all?

[enter image description here][image: 1]

Comment: Side note: `'Batch separator: SELECT'` is pure evil

Comment: I can not fathom why anyone would use select for that. Does this mean you have seen this used? Or do you mean someone using it as a prank?

Comment: The more I think on it... that is a better prank than the run time one they did to me. that would be pure evil.